# How to extract parameters of a function and use them in another function that uses 2 different results from the 1st function?

Tags: python, tkinter, sorcery

New to coding, not sure how to ask this. I have a function that creates buttons:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)

def create_button(location_name, position_x, position_y):
    Button(root, text = location_name).place(x=position_x, y=position_y, width=60, height=20)

a = create_button("A",20,30)
b = create_button("B",70,80)

canvas.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

I want to create a function that makes a line between any button. For example with A and B it has to take into account the parameters of A (position_x, position_y) and parameters of B (position_x, position_y). Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Why make a function for this and not just do it in the layout? Are you looking to do it as an event, when you click something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3008220/conor-thompson What do you mean by "do it in the layout" ? It's easy to manually calculate the coordinates of each button and then create a line, but it's very time consuming if I have to do it for several hundreds of them. So I was just wondering if it was possible to do it in a more automated way, by putting the parameters of the 2 buttons i want to connect in a specific function that creates lines. I dont want to do it as an event, I want the lines to be there forever, if I may say so.

Comment: Normally in building a Tkinter app you would build the layout separately, the buttons, images etc. So for each button you want to have a line between each of the buttons as main style? Do you mean like a pipe '|' or __? Sorry, just trying to understand the question more.

Comment: what you're trying to do here should be done with a class. managing the size, positions, root window... You can automate layout creation, but if it's simple. What do you want the layout to look like? To automate something it must always have a procedural way of generating it.

Comment: Not a line for all buttons, but yes that's the idea. I'm trying to reproduce an interactive map for a video game. Each button represents a location. Some buttons have several connexions (= linked with several lines), some buttons only have 1 connexion (= linked by only 1 line). For example in the code I wrote, to make a line between A and B you would write :    canvas.create_line((50,40),(100,90)). This line will go exactly from the center of Button A to the center of Button B. It's easy to manually do it for each connexion,but it's quite time consuming. Maybe there's an easier way to do it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2076832/graygoose124 How would it help if it was done in a class ? Could you explain please ?

Comment: Give me one moment and I'll mock up an example

Comment: I had to go out, but here's something to ponder over: https://gist.github.com/GRAYgoose124/9e0154def711af8517a7884337b03fdc

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take the time look at this in detail. I don't know if I'll understand every math reference but I'm sure it will help.

Comment: simply create list/dictionary to keep this data and then you can get infromation from this list/dictionary to create buttons and lines instead of thinking how to get it from function.

Comment: BTW: your function doesn't use `return` to return button or any other value so `a` and `b` will be `None`

Answer (score 1):

You should keep this data as list or dictionary and then you can use them with many functions

```
# --- functions ---

def create_button(name):
    x, y = points[name]

    button = Button(root, text=name)
    button.place(x=x, y=y, width=60, height=20)

    return button

def create_line(name1, name2):
    x1, y1 = points[name1]
    x2, y2 = points[name2]

    line = canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, ...)

    return line

# --- main ---

points = {
    "A": [20,30], 
    "B": [70,80],
}

buttons = {}
lines = {}

buttons["A"] = create_button("A")
buttons["B"] = create_button("B")
lines[("A", "B")] = create_line("A", "B")
```

You can even use `for` loop to create it

```
points = {
    "A": [20,30], 
    "B": [70,80],
    "C": [50,0]
}

connections = [
    ("A", "B"), # or "AB" but it needs modification in `for`
    ("A", "C"),
    #("B", "C") # you can skip some connections
]

buttons = {}
lines = {}

for name in points.keys():
    buttons[name] = create_button(name)

for name1, name2 in connections:
    lines[(name1, name2)] = create_line(name1, name2)
    #lines[(name2, name1)] = lines[(name1, name2)] # "AB" = "BA"
```

BTW: and later you can read `points` and `connections` from file.

---

**BTW:** there is module [Networx](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/networkx-1.11/tutorial/) to work with `graphs` which have `nodes` and `edges` (`points` and `connections`) but it can be not so usefull for you. See: [random draw](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/networkx-1.11/examples/drawing/random_geometric_graph.html).

Comment: Thank you so much furas. I'm trying to understand each line as I'm writing it, because I don't know much about list/dictionary yet. This will be very helpful, thanks a lot.